# Unable to convert HTML to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I'm able to download a PDF using jsPDF but the downloaded PDF is plain text excluding the styles applied in the website.

I am unable to get the styles or formatting in the website to the downloadable PDF.

Here's the jsPDF code I use:

```
       <button type="button" onclick="convert()" class="pda-button"><i class="save-icon sprite"></i> Save</button>

        <div  id="content">
          //content goes 
        </div>
        <div id="elementH"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.codexworld.com/includes/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.codexworld.com/3rd-party/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>  

        <script>
    function convert() {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var elementHTML = $('#content').html();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

        // Save the PDF
        doc.save('sample-document.pdf');
    }
    </script>
```

Here's the link to website I integrated the above code and want to convert to PDF:
[Website's link](http://appgrep.com/demo/en/indexx.php)

As I click on **save** button on the top left of the site to download PDF, the PDF is generated and downloaded but as an plain text PDF with no styles.

**And Please do not Down-Vote the post without explaining the reason for doing so..**

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a callback function to the method **doc.fromHTML**

```
doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    }, function cb() {} );
```

**cb()** will tell you that the pdf is ready.